# IIS 7 Access Denied for local IP but not Localhost

Tags: visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller, iis, iis-7

I've just started to experience this error. I'm developing MVC apps and using visual studio to deploy to my inetpub/wwwroot directory.

When i publish and hit the site at http://localhost the site works as expected.

When i hit the site using my IP address http://192.168.16.216 i get the following error

> Unable to display page It has not been possible to display the page
>   you requested for the following reason: Access Denied Contact your
>   system administrator if you continue to experience difficulties.

I get this error on all browsers. I'm running IIS7 on Windows 7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using your network IP means you'll be going out and back in again. Is your router configured to allow access to your machine on port 80? I'm guessing that http://127.0.0.1 works as expected?

Comment: Jamie, 127.0.0.1 does work, i'm guessing our office router won't be configured. I'll check but i expect you're right. Thanks for that.

Comment: Iam also facing the same problem in IIS7 of Windows7 OS, when i type "localhost" iam getting the IIS7 Page but when i type with ip address iam getting the below error Message "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found." Thanks in Advance......... Thanks,
-Dinesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment above:

> Using your network IP means you'll be going out and back in again. Is your router configured to allow access to your machine on port 80?

It's likely that your company router isn't allowing access to your machine on port 80.